# How does Google Plus' Photos guess which photos to include in a story?

Tags: google-plus-photos

I took about 30 photos on differente places (in Azores), different days, using my DSLR. I uploaded those photos with minimal metadata to Google's Photos. Some weeks later I get a notification saying my new story is ready. What??

So Google Plus woke up that day I guessed that 12 of those 30 photos would make part of a story called "A sunday night in Azores". How did it guessed Azores? Why those 12? Why not the whole 30?

So my main question is: **How does Google Plus' Photos guess which photos to include in a story?**

- How does it work with photos uploaded instead of taken (with camera app)?
- Can we guide/tweak the algorithm by giving clues?
- Can we trigger that behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile Google Photos was released, which includes an "Assistant" that let's you pick photos to create custom stories. Problem solved, thanks Google.